# How to fix cannot read property "send" of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This question might have a few duplicates, but the code there is different and none of the answers work for me. I'm new to discord.js so it might just be a silly mistake.

This is my code -

```js
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
client.on('message', function(message) {
    if (message.startsWith('^')) { //condition is false, even though message starts with ^
        if (message.startsWith('^ping')) {
            message.mentions.users.forEach((k, v) => {
                message.channel.send('Hello,' + v + '!');
            });
        } else if (message.startsWith('^dice')) {
            message.channel.send('You rolled a a' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + "!");
        } else {
            message.channel.send("Command not found.");
        }
    } else {
        message.channel.send("debug") //error in this line
    }
});
```

I really don't know how to fix this, so all the solutions I have tried lead to this error.
Also if you see any other fixes to this code please point it out. Here is the error:

```
        message.channel.send("debug")
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at DiscordClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Documents\UltraBot\bot.js:32:25)
    at DiscordClient.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at DiscordClient.handleWSMessage (C:\Users\user\Documents\UltraBot\node_modules\discord.io\lib\index.js:1854:11)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.ontext (C:\Users\user\Documents\UltraBot\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:841:10)
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\UltraBot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:536:18
    at Receiver.applyExtensions (C:\Users\user\Documents\UltraBot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:371:5)
    at C:\Users\user\Documents\UltraBot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:508:14
    at Receiver.flush (C:\Users\user\Documents\UltraBot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:347:3)
    at Receiver.finish (C:\Users\user\Documents\UltraBot\node_modules\ws\lib\Receiver.js:541:12)
```

Comment: have you tried `console.log()`ing the message, or the channel, to see what is the root of the problem?

Comment: Another problem is that you should be using `message.content.startsWith()` instead of `message.startsWith()`. Also, you tagged this discord.js when you are using discord.io. Are you purposefully using discord.io?

Comment: @Levi_OP i tried console logging a message before the line with the error and it did, but when i added .content after message it gives this:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined`

Comment: look at my answer and https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.io#example

Comment: Now my bot doesn't go online when i run `node bot.js`. Is there something different i should do?

Comment: Did you read my answer? You are using the wrong packages and the wrong code!

Comment: I used your code and installed discord.io , am i missing something?

Comment: Discord.io is for browsers! You want to be using disocrd.js instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using code for [Discord.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js), while using the [Discord.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.io) package. The ways that you send and receive messages is vastly different. I suggest that you switch to discord.js, as that is what you are writing the code to work for.

Comment: Should i make any changes to the start of the code?

Comment: go to https://discord.js.org for info on what your code should look like and how to set it up.